# FMDB update version number doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, fmdb

I know how to use FMDB for the basic functions like create database table etc.

When i want to update my table like add a new column i need to update the user version number.

FMDB has a `userVersion` property should be sqlite's `user_version`. I used below code:

```
if let db = DBManager.shared.database, db.userVersion == 0, db.open() {
     addColumnsToSomeTable()
     db.userVersion = 1
}
```

But run the project, the `userVersion` still 0. It should be 1 and this if block shouldn't be entered in.

Why the userVersion can't be upgraded?

I also tried:

```
let string = "PRAGMA user_version = 1"
do {
  try db.executeUpdate(string, values: nil)
} catch {    
}
```

Still the same problem.

I searched some tutorials, most of them has the `fileExists` check like below:

```
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbPath) {
        database = FMDatabase(path: dbPath)
    }
```

What's the sense here? If file exist what's the correct way to get it? 
 Not the same as : `database = FMDatabase(path: dbPath)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the sqlite software `DB Browser for SQLite` at the same time. Close it, then works fine.